# Populate Combobox with values from table1 minus table2 - Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looking for a way to populate a combobox from two tables. The values in table2 are a selection from table1.
What I want to achieve is a combobox with the values from table1 minus the values from table2.
I thought about finding the duplicates and remove the pairs but I don't know if thats a rational way.

Comment: Loop over Table1 and add the item if it's not found in Table2.  Did you try anything yet?

Comment: Hey Tim, thanks for your suggestion. I didn't try anything, but will now with your idea. I'm starting out with VBA and sometimes don't know where and how to start

Comment: Hi Stephan, take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and earn your first badge!

Comment: [Please don't add "solved" to your title or question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/116105/248627). Instead, [mark an answer correct by clicking on the checkmark](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/248627). You can also [add your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and accept it if none of the ones you received solved your problem.

Comment: Hi Chris, I'm a bit lost, because I think if my question is closed, I can't answer. I don't have a text field to for that.

Comment: That's correct, closed questions cannot be answered. That doesn't change the Q&A format required here. This question has two reopen votes on it; if it gets reopened you can post your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

### Range1 Minus Range2 to Combo Box in MS365

- It is assumed everything is located in `Sheet1` of the workbook containing the code.
- In MS365, you could use the following formula:

  ```
  =FILTER(A2:A11,ISNA(XMATCH(A2:A11,C2:C5)))
  ```
- You can 'convert' to VBA using the following:

```vb
Sub NotFoundToCombo()
     
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
        
        Dim rg1 As Range: Set rg1 = .Range("A2:A11")
        Dim rg2 As Range: Set rg2 = .Range("C2:C5")
    
        Dim Data() As Variant
        
        With Application
            Data = .Filter(rg1, .IsNA(.XMatch(rg1, rg2)))
        End With

        '.Range("E2").Resize(UBound(Data, 1)).Value = Data
        
        .ComboBox1.List = Data
    
    End With

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: I'm not on MS365, have to deal with 2016.